# Two-fingered scroll js on touchpad

Tags: javascript, jquery, touchpad

We have developed a site whcih has a horizontal orientation and are wanting to implement touchpad control with two fingers move left/right.

When you move two fingers left/right on touchpad, the site page is being scrolled left/right. Now we have implemented touchpad control with two fingers move up/down and page scrolled left/right.

How can we change touchpad control with two fingers move from up/down to left/right to scroll site page left/right using js or jQuery?

Comment: Isn't scrolling handled by the OS (or the browser) not the website?

Answer (score 11):

I may be a little late but had the same question before I stumbled over this question.
A little further investigation lead me to think that the best bet to capture trackpad scrolling would be the `wheel` event.

```
function doScroll(e) {
    // positive deltas are top and left
    // down and right are negative

    // horizontal offset    e.deltaX
    // vertical offset      e.deltaY

    console.log(`x:${e.deltaX} y:${e.deltaY}`);

    e.preventDefault(); // disable the actual scrolling
}

window.addEventListener("wheel", doScroll, false);
```

I have prepared [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/64p5r459/2/) that tells you the scroll direction and offset values but prevents the scrolling itself.

The [wheel event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent) has a delta property that (at least in Chrome) is sensitive to momentum and gives you the current relative scroll offset rather than the absolute scroll position available in the `scroll` event.

Comment: little late, but a little great.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you want to take over touch events in script, you add something like this to prevent the usual scroll and zoom:

```
$("body").bind("touchstart", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Got it.But how can i detect/listen events of two fingers on touchpad on MacOs machines in browsers that are built on WebKit engines (for example, Safari)? I want catch these events to prevent then the defoult scrolling actions in this browser.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is change what can be scrolled.  If your page is big enough where left/right scrolling makes sense, the browser will allow it be scrolled that way.

Basically, if you only want them scrolling in a certain direction, only make content in that direction.  If necessary, you can achieve this by having a container div of the specific size you want with overflow set to none.