# Detect events of touchpad two fingers scrolling on MacOs in Safari

Tags: javascript, macos

We are working on site scrolling. Our site has horizantal orientation, and page resize developed so that there is no a vertical browser scroll to the any pages. 
But when we tested our site on MacOs machine we have a bug with touchpad two fingers scrolling in browsers that are built on WebKit engine (for example, Safari).

In scrolling process we have following results (Safari browser MacOs):

1) if i scroll up/down with two fingers on touchpad page moves up/down (but here is no the vertical browser scroll) and just then page moves/scrolls to the left/right as we need;

2) if i scroll left/right with two fingers on touchpad the browser tabs begin to scroll/leaf, we need that this action scrolls our page to the left/right side or prevent this action.

Therefore, We need to catch events of touchpad two fingers scrolling on MacOs in browsers that are built on WebKit engine.

Maybe someone knows How can we detect/listen events of touchpad/trackpad (two fingers on touchpad) by using javascript?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472889/touch-events-available-in-safari

Comment: Maybe here is some solutions for Webkit browsers? Or how can i prevent defoult events for touchpadscrolling with to fingers for Safari and Chrome browsers?

Comment: Do you consider using external libraries? I would recommend using hammer.js to do so, it's a great library for detecting complex touch events in browsers :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two-fingered scroll js on touchpad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977876/two-fingered-scroll-js-on-touchpad)